# Is it possible to disable my touchscreen so that I can work again properly?

Tags: 14.04, asus, touchscreen

I have a notebook Asus VivoBook with a touchscreen, but the drivers are not working properly and interfere with my mouse.

Is it possible to disable my touchscreen so that I can work again properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find you touchscreen ID:

   ```
   xinput list
   ```
2. Disable it:

   ```
   xinput disable ID
   ```
3. You can add it to the *Startup Applications* tool so that you don't need to run it each time you log in.